# listar una informacion de una Api con React pero solo retorna el ultimo valor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, map, fetch

Hola estoy usando react y una api creada con Strapi, el problema que tengo ahora es que intento traer datos de la api, efectivamente me trae la informacion con el fetch y cuando hago el .map solo me muestra el ultimo valor, mas no el listado de toda la api.

Este es el codigo del home donde se lee la api y se pasan los datos al componente correspondiente, como pueden ver hago un fetch y ejecuto una funcion de la api de Strapi que es getEntries, las cuales despues las almaceno en el state y lo paso por props al componente correspondiente el cuales .

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Slider from '../components/Slider'
import Services from '../components/Services'
import Projects from '../components/Projects'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import Strapi from 'strapi-sdk-javascript/build/main';

const strapi = new Strapi('http://localhost:1337');

const Home = () => {
    const [service, setServices] = useState ();
    const [project, setProjects] = useState ();
    const [slider, setSliders] = useState ();
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    useEffect( ()  => {

        if(service ===undefined ){
            const Fetch = async () => {
                try {
                    const gets = await strapi.getEntries("Services")
                    setServices(gets);
                    
                  } 
                  catch(err) {
                   alert(err);
                  }
            } 

          Fetch();

        }
        if(project===undefined){
            const Fetch = async () => {
                try {
                    const getProject = await strapi.getEntries("Projects")
                    setProjects( getProject );

                    
                  } 
                  catch(err) {
                   alert(err);
                  }
            } 

          Fetch();

        }
        if(slider===undefined){
            const Fetch = async () => {
                try {

                    const getSlider = await strapi.getEntries("Sliders")
                    setSliders( getSlider );
                  } 
                  catch(err) {
                   alert(err);
                  }
            } 

          Fetch();

        }
     });
           
            
    
    return (

        <React.Fragment>
    
    <Header />
    
    <Slider slider={slider} />
 
    <Services service={service} />

    <Projects project={project}/>

    <Footer />
    
    </React.Fragment>
        
)
}

export default Home
```

Ahora podemos ver el codigo del componente donde se deberia de desplegar todos los datos de la api, pero solo me muestra el ultimo. Aqui podemos ver que llamo un recurso de react el cual es un slider que recibe ciertos parametros como titulo descripcion e imagen; como se logra ver estoy recibiendo las props que envie desde el home y hago un .map de los datos recibidos con la props y los envio al state para despues desplegarlos en cada elemento necesario.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import './styles/Projects.css'
import './styles/Carousel.css'
import Slider from 'react-animated-slider';
import 'react-animated-slider/build/horizontal.css';
import './styles/slider-animations.css';

const Projects = (props:any) => {
    const [id,setId]= useState();
    const [title, setTitle] = useState();
    const [description, setDescription] = useState();
    const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState();
    const [category, setCategory] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        
        if(props.project !== undefined){
            props.project.map((data:any) => {
                setId(data.id)
                setTitle(data.title);
                setDescription(data.description);
                setCategory(data.services[0].title);
                setImgUrl(data.image.url)
            })
        }
    })


    return (

        <div className="container-projects">
        <div className="row cont-project align-items-center">
            
            <div className="col-12 text-center">
                <h1 className="title-projects">Recent <br/>work</h1>
            </div>
             <div>

            <Slider className="slider-wrapper">
                
                    <div
                        key={id}
                        className="slider-content"
                        style={{ background: `url('http://localhost:1337${imgUrl}') no-repeat center center` }}
                    >
                        <div className="inner">
                            <h1>{title}</h1>
                            <p>{description}</p>
                            <button>More..</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            </Slider>
     </div>
        </div>
        
    
        </div>
    )
 
    
    }

export default Projects
```

Me parece muy raro por que ya he intentado diferentes funciones para consumir datos de una api, y no se como seguir, ya que tambien quiero listar un menu de cada titulo de los proyectos, tambien adjunto la api para que vean la estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En tu componente Project en tu effect estas asignando cada valor en el mismo state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(props.project !== undefined){
        props.project.map((data:any) => {
            setId(data.id)
            setTitle(data.title);
            setDescription(data.description);
            setCategory(data.services[0].title);
            setImgUrl(data.image.url)
        })
    }
})
```

por ejemplo, cada vez que iteras, ejecutas `setId` y el valor actual lo asignas a `id`, es por eso que siempre te muestra solo el ultimo item.

Lo que podrias hacer es iterar en el componente padre de tu componente Projects y en Projects solo muestra la info usando los props. Otra opcion seria que en lugar de hacer los sets dentro del map mejor hagas el render ahi.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(props.project !== undefined){
        props.project.map((data:any) => {
            return (
               <div>{data.title}</div>
               ...etc
            )
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Lo intente haciendo el render ahi mismo en el map, y mira el error que me sale ahora.

TypeScript error in C:/xampp/htdocs/Code/web-algoritmo/src/pages/home.tsx(81,5):
JSX element type 'void' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.  TS2605